# TV-PC via HDMI trouble

Tags: hdmi, tv

I connected my TV to my PC(it's the only screen I have connected to it, the HDMI cable works) and after the Windows logo, nothing shows up, just the TV showing HDMI3 port, although PC is running.

It works in Safe mode, so could the problem be the graphics card?

I have Zotac 560Ti and I've used this setup about 3 months ago and it worked flawlessly by just inserted the HDMI cable to the TV. Now it doesnt show anything after the logo. I've tried downgrading the graphics card driver, still no response. I can't change anything by pressing win+p, for those who might suggest it, because I can't get to my desktop.

Suggstions on next steps?

Comment: Does your TV have a vga connection you can use while you diagnose?

Comment: This sounds like a simple driver problem.

Comment: This could very well be an issue of Resolution, since you say it works in Safe Mode.  What I mean, is that when you boot normally, the resolution and/or refresh rate may be outside the range of the TV.  Instead of booting to Safe Mode, try booting to VGA mode (Vista and W7).  Then, set a larger resolution, and keep choosing the next step up until you get to one that works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have access to a external monitor. To be able to check the video setting and if the OS is even finding the TV or giving you an error. I have also seen when Windows will read the ONLY monitor as the second one and will display black when the log in screen shows up. So you need to try and log on like you normally would, hit enter then type in password then see if the screen shows up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you switch from having a second monitor and not having a second monitor. Because of this I would recommend going through the set up process for having a second monitor again. While Windows is usually good about this it can make mistakes every once in a while. The recommended way to go about setting up a monitor for multiple Windows operating systems can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx#fbid=tnCWKWhgfXS).